# Automatically copy an item from one attribute to another

Tags: python, odoo

In odoo there is the possibility to automatically copy what you put in another field ?. For example, a document depends on a date but the detail of the document must also have the same date and I do not want to put it manually every time but I want the one I put to be automatically copied. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Look at https://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorator.html#api-onchange

Comment: Use this code to copy the date from one table to another but it is not copied.
@ api.onchange ('document_id')
      def _check_date (self):
          self.date = self.document_id.date

Comment: Check if `date` field is readonly, if so it will not work with `onchange`.